# Where's my phone mounted to browse it from shell?

Tags: command-line, mountpoint

I have connected a smartphone and would like to copy some file onto it using midnight commander. I've found out that the mount point is `mtp://[usb:002,004]/Card/` however when I try to run `cd mtp://[usb:002,004]/Card/` I get `No such file or directory`. How should I point to it in terminal?

Comment: Try to drag a folder out of your file manager onto the terminal. It's path should appear.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this has two main problems:

- It won't understand the path `mtp://[usb:001,009]/SD%20card`
- It likely won't want to use `[`, `,`, `]` etc in the path name - spaces may cause issues as well.

On my system, `mtp://[usb:001,009]/SD card/` shows up as this in terminal:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C009%5D/SD card
```

So for your device you will likely have to do:

```
cd "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C004%5D/"
```

Where:

- Its in quotes so it can do the name with the space.
- The `1000` (probably) is User ID - you may have to replace it with `${UID}` (or just the value of `echo $UID`). On some systems it may be the name of the user (so `echo $USER`).
- The subdirectories of the mounted MTP device likely will be `phone` (or `Internal storage`) and `SD card` (or just `card`), depending on your setup.

Comment: It works but still I cannot copy by MC because of `operation not supported`... a pity because graphical file manager hangs when I try to copy big file. I'll try later from different system. Thanks, anyway