# How to have access to MTP mounted devices?

Tags: dolphin, mtp

I wanted to transfer photos from my smartphone to my computer. The file explorer is Dolphin. I can find the file to be copied on the path : mtp:/HUAWEI_NXT ... but when I try to cd to the folder, I have the error:  `No such file or directory`. I read following forums:

https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/mtp

[Where's my phone mounted to browse it from shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664089/wheres-my-phone-mounted-to-browse-it-from-shell)

https://qastack.fr/ubuntu/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem

But none of them is helping. I do lsusb, and I have information mentioned in the second link. However when I do : `cd mtp://[usb:002,018]/` I have: `No such file or directory`.

Can anyone help me with that?
Best regards.

Comment: The second link was already a duplicate: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem

Comment: I saw this one. When I do  cd mtp://[usb:002,018]/ I have : No such file or directory. And when I go to /run/user/1000/gvfs, it is empty.

Comment: Did you enable the connection *on the phone*?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I would not see the content of files with the explorer. Is not true ?

Comment: True, but that is not clear in your question above. Comments here are intended to help you clarify and refine your question. Consider adding clarifications to your question above. Many folks do not read comments.

Comment: The answer I linked to does not require you to do `cd mtp://...`, that is in fact bad syntax. Instead, look for the proper USB values in `/run/user/$USER/gvfs` and construct a `cd` statement of the form ` cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D/`` .

Comment: Are you sure 1000 is your UID? Try `echo $UID`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, /run/user/1000/gvfs is empty for me. Where the information "host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D/" can come from ?

Comment: I tried echo $UID and the answer is 1000.